# mod_rewrite rule to change parent folder

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Some unchangeable hyperlinks on a website point to `/folderA/index.php?id=somestuff`.
I need to redirect the Request to `/folderB/index.php?id=somestuff` instead.

I did some experimenting with this but I just can't get it to work, any help is appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /folderA/index\.php\?id=([\w-]+)$ /folderB/index.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Is "somestuff" dynamic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that RewriteRule doesn't match query string and matches only REQUEST_URI without it. Use this code instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+folderA/(index\.php\?id=[^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /folderB/%1 [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are not planning on using different get request this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /folderA/index\.php\?id=(.*?)$ /folderB/index.php?id=$1
```

Comment: As I wrote in my answer as well: `Keep in mind that RewriteRule doesn't match query string and matches only REQUEST_URI without it`